# Convince gdb to reveal type of unhandled exception

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb

How does one convince gdb to reveal the type of an unhandled exception. I have a core dump and its associated binary and a stack trace in gdb shows me that it was in an catch all handler like so:

```
try { ... }
catch (exception &x) { ... }
catch (...)
{
-> here <-
}
```

The last part of the stack trace is:

> 0  0x00000034dc432925 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>
> 1  0x00000034dc434105 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
>
> 2  0x00000034dc80dec1 in unwind_cleanup () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
>
> 4  ... my catch (...) handler
>
> 5  ... rest of call stack leading up to this ...

So I up up up to get to the stack point in the catch (...) but am now stuck trying to figure out what the exception type was. Any gdb tips to reveal it?
Note that its mustard after the meal now (i mean i can't run it again and wait for this same problem to occur again as it is few and far inbetween) so can't catch gxx_personality_v0 any more to gain access to its variables pertaining to the exception unless someone has an idea how to get to it given my situation explained above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value and type of the current exception in C++ using gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313227/how-do-i-get-the-value-and-type-of-the-current-exception-in-c-using-gdb)

Comment: I have edited the question to explain why I can't see it to be answered by the suggested question